# Change ASP to Java technology?

Tags: java, servlets, graphics, asp-classic, applet

I need help on how to propose a new website. I don’t know how to start and I hope you can guide me( if it is better to make an applet , a servlet, use other technology, etc. ) .

I have a website in ASP, it reads text files that are on the server in the same directory as the web . There are n files (may be about 300 plain text files generated by an external application ) . The website only read them, generates a menu with the data they contain . Depending on the selected menu options , read a specific files and pass this information to Flash movies which generate statistical graphs.

Flash movies are very old and actually cause problems in browsers. They can’t be loaded on all platforms for example. And the ASP technology is also obsolete.

We want to change the technology and create a web that reads a series of text files hosted on the server and pass these parameters to a graphic (we would use javascript libraries, for example Morris). We are interested for JAVA. What you recommend?. if its JAVA , this can be done with Applets ? or Should we use servlets?? or Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Personally, if you going down this track, use Servlets over Applets.  You can generate the graphics as images and serve them via the container/server - IMHO

Comment: I don't think that ASP Classic is obsolete, but... You need generate some charts, right? Why don't you use one based on JavaScript, like Google Charts? I Use this with ASP and it works great. Please, take a look here: 

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery

Comment: Applets are as obsolete as classic ASP, and they also require the end user to have Java installed.  Use Servlets. Then Java only needs to be installed on the server. I would also suggest using a Javascript library for the charts if you don't have the Flash app already.

Comment: I'd have to agree with @MadProgrammer here.  Using applets would be a backwards step.  If you want to offer a rich client, abandon the browser completely and deploy a desktop app using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 0):

I use amcharts (http://www.amcharts.com/) to generate our charts. 
I build the data using classic ASP  ... then pass to an array in JS and then use the amcharts tools, which are very powerful and flexible.